# add toolbar to jquery-easyui combogrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I'm looking for a way to add the toolbar to combogrid option in jquery-easyui.
Is it possible to add the toolbar to the jquery-easyui combogrid?

Thanks in advance,

Kluther

EDIT 20130620: The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="jquery,ui,easy,easyui,web">
<meta name="description" content="easyui help you build your web page easily!">
<title>jQuery EasyUI CRUD Demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h2>Basic CRUD Application</h2>
<div class="demo-info" style="margin-bottom:10px">
    <div class="demo-tip icon-tip">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>Click the buttons on datagrid toolbar to do crud actions.</div>
</div>

<table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px"
        url="get_users.php"
        toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
        rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th field="firstname" width="50">First Name</th>
            <th field="lastname" width="50">Last Name</th>
            <th field="phone" width="50">Phone</th>
            <th field="email" width="50">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<div id="toolbar">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-add" plain="true" onclick="newUser()">New User</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editUser()">Edit User</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-remove" plain="true" onclick="destroyUser()">Remove User</a>
</div>

<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:400px;height:280px;padding:10px 20px"
        closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
    <div class="ftitle">User Information</div>
    <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>First Name:</label>
            <input name="firstname" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Last Name:</label>
            <!--<input name="lastname" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">-->
            <select class="easyui-combogrid" style="width:150px" name="lastname" data-options="  
                panelWidth: 160,
                toolbar:'#toolbar',  
                idField: 'id',  
                textField: 'lastname',  
                url: 'last_names.json',  
                columns: [[  
                    {field:'id',title:'ID',width:20},  
                    {field:'lastname',title:'Lastname',width:100}  

                ]],  
                fitColumns: true  
            ">  
        </select>
        <!--<select id="cc" style="width:150px" required="true" name="lastname"></select>-->
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Phone:</label>
            <input name="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input name="email" class="easyui-validatebox" validType="email">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="dlg-buttons">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="saveUser()">Save</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Cancel</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


    var url;
    function newUser(){
        $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','New User');
        $('#fm').form('clear');
        url = 'save_user.php';
    }
    function editUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit User');
            $('#fm').form('load',row);
            url = 'update_user.php?id='+row.id;
        }
    }
    function saveUser(){
        $('#fm').form('submit',{
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(result){
                var result = eval('('+result+')');
                if (result.errorMsg){
                    $.messager.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: result.errorMsg
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function destroyUser(){
        var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
        if (row){
            $.messager.confirm('Confirm','Are you sure you want to destroy this user?',function(r){
                if (r){
                    $.post('destroy_user.php',{id:row.id},function(result){
                        if (result.success){
                            $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                        } else {
                            $.messager.show({   // show error message
                                title: 'Error',
                                msg: result.errorMsg
                            });
                        }
                    },'json');
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    #fm{
        margin:0;
        padding:10px 30px;
    }
    .ftitle{
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:bold;
        padding:5px 0;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .fitem{
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }
    .fitem label{
        display:inline-block;
        width:80px;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is a combination of the datagrid example and the combigrid example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just give the  "toolbar : '#toolbarid'" in the data-options.

Comment: Hi Saigitha, have you ever tried this yourself? I know that you can use  "toolbar : '#toolbarid'" in the datagrid. But in the combogrid? I have tried it just now, but the toolbar does not appear.

Comment: Yes , tried. its working.. can you post your code. so that i can find out the issue.

Comment: Can you try to use different toolbar for the combogrid.. you are referring the same toolbar in datagrid and combogrid.. can you create one more tool bar with different id and refer it in combogrid?

Comment: Thanks Saigitha,this works! I'm sorry but I don't have enough points to up your answer.